# Importing class then passing argument to function

Tags: python

I have a python file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from bead import Ford

szotar = {"The" : "A", "sun": "nap", "shining" : "süt", "wind" : "szél", "not" : "nem", "blowing" : "fúj"}

fd = Ford(szotar)
fd.fordit("teszt.txt")
```

I have to write the Ford class, which has a fordit function, which opens the file passed as the argument. I wrote this:

```
class Ford(dict):
    def fordit(read):
        fajl = open(read)
        for sor in fajl:
            print(sor)
        fajl.close()
```

But I get the error "TypeError: fordit() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)". What is the problem?

Comment: You have to declare the `self` argument explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't define `fordit` with the necessary arguments. `f.fordit(x)` is equivalent to `Ford.fordit(f, x)`, so you need to define it to take *two* arguments, the first being the object calling the method and conventionally (but not necessarily) named `self`.

(Unrelated, but you should use a `with` statement, which ensures that the file is closed even if an error occurs while it is open. The file is closed implicitly once the `with` statement completes.)

```
class Ford(dict):
    def fordit(self, read):
        with open(read) as fajl:
            for sor in fajl:
                print(sor)
```